# Lowercase methods for Gorilla xmlrpc

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm using [Gorilla XMLRPC](https://github.com/divan/gorilla-xmlrpc). As per the example,

```
func (h *HelloService) Say(r     *http.Request, 
                           args  *struct{Who string}, 
                           reply *struct{Message string}) error {
    reply.Message = "Hello, " + args.Who + "!"
    return nil
}
```

and `RPC.RegisterService(new(HelloService), "")` gives me a service `HelloService.Say()`. I would like to have `helloService.say()`. I was able to get the first part by modifying the register function to `RPC.RegisterService(new(HelloService), "helloService")`. But I'm not able to make lowercase methods exported.

I understand golang allows only uppercase methods to be exported. So is there any work-around for lowercase methods?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue today. This problem was [solved](https://github.com/divan/gorilla-xmlrpc/commit/32b6cdbb2f3807e15a28571dbc86735ee0451665) in gorilla-xmlrpc a couple of years ago. Now you can register an alias on the xmlrpc codec:

```
myCodec := xml.NewCodec()
myCodec.RegisterAlias("MyType.lowerCaseMethod", "MyType.UpperCaseMethod")
```

Input with e.g. `<methodName>MyType.lowerCaseMethod</methodName>` will be recognized as expected.

This function is noted in the godoc but not mentioned in the project README or related examples.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first question is "why does it need to be [lowercase] "say" and the second question would need to be, if it needed to be that way, why use Go?

It's a convention that Uppercase methods and properties are exported and lowercase methods and properties are private.

Comment: 1. It has to be lowercase because I have to integrate with existing systems.    
2. Agreed. I may have to write this piece in python. But I wanted to explore if there are options.